# declined reopening the suitable question: what should I do

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, declined-flags

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/1206998) that I have looked a few times (I've got a bad memory :-). It is marked as duplicate, but as many others (see comments) I thought this question is actually the most suitable of his duplicate. Briefly the reason are:

1. the question is better formulated (more specific) than the other one(s)
2. the answers are clearer and more complete
3. it appears first in google
4. it has much more views and votes (due to 1, 2 and 3)

Up to here, I just up the "please reopen the question" comment.

However, not long ago I found this alternate solution which is, to my sincere opinion, better in all aspects: more efficient and more readable. Thus I flagged for moderator attention, saying everything and asking to reopen the question. But it was declined [(don't know why)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35431/193470).

Now, what should I do?

1. Don't share my knowledge and go back to work?
2. Put my opinion (and ego) aside and post my answer on a non-duplicated duplicate?
3. Find the moderator's address and send him a horse head?

Comment: That is a valid answer you could post (even if I don't like it...)

Comment: What would be "blatantly better"?
Votes is about a 321 vs 122. 
1 line question vs a page (with lots of unrelated 'django'stuff)

Comment: Opening a meta question about it is probably the best idea.  I agree, the question with the highest votes/views should be the canonical, and the others should be closed / merged into it (if possible). Along with that there should be some answer cleanup. So this isn't really a 5 minute thing if you it done right. I've 'favorited' this question and will take a look later today if another moderator hasn't already done so.

Comment: There's something I don't quite understand.  What is behind the apparent fascination with this particular Stack Overflow question?  It's got 163758 views and 8 posted answers.  You claim that your answer is better than all the others.  Yet it seems like an ordinary (dare I say mundane?) computing problem, which is almost certainly already adequately covered by the other answers.  Is this some sort of nerd-fest?  I don't get it.

Comment: My solution is just a little better, but I like it :-). I think the fascination come from 2 things: mainly it is a problem often encounter by python coders, and second it is really representative of the research for best "pythonic" codes, which we all care for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, to justify asking a moderator to move duplicates around (reopening, then closing the old target as the new duplicate), it really needs to be a blatantly better question.

Without being familiar with the topic at hand, I'm only judging by what the questions look like and I think your argument has 3 things going for it.

1. The question in reference here was closed as a duplicate the same day it was asked after only 90 minutes, so most of those views and votes came **after** it was closed.  It also means the community simply closed it because it was newer and not because it was better.
2. The answers on the question your reference seem more complete.
3. The question is simpler and to the point, which I think makes it a better duplicate target.

So the question really becomes how do you judge what "blatantly" better is.

- First, voting is not always the best indicator, especially because you are talking about 2 questions that are each 5+ years old and each have hundreds of votes.  Its not like you are dealing with a post with 300 votes vs 3 votes or questions that were asked 3 or 4 years apart.
- And both questions have answers with 100+ votes.  Views isn't a great measure either, simply because you are dealing with 2 questions that have a significant number of views to have earned their OP a gold badge.
- You also have to consider whether the duplicate target is a more general or canonical question.  There was a time when CW questions were used in this manner, so it would have been natural to close a newer question in favor of a canonical CW question.  I don't necessarily think that, in this specific case, the older question really looks to be more of a canonical post, but it still needs to be considered.
- The Google rank does certainly help with the views and the votes as well, but a lot also depends on the search terms.  I tried a few variations of the words in both titles and your question in reference comes out on top more often than the duplicate target, but that could also be solved by changing the title of the duplicate target.

---

### TL;DR;

In the end, I think the question you want to reopen is a better question mostly because of what appears to be better quality answers and a more simple, to-the-point question, but I don't think it is necessarily leaps and bounds better to bother a moderator about moving the duplicates around.

Not speaking for the mods, but starting to move duplicates around because a handful of people think that this 5 year old question might be slightly better than that 5 year old question seems a waste of time, and time that could be better spent handling other flags.

---

### All this being said

There's nothing to stop you from doing it yourself without mod intervention.  It is difficult to do on the fly without having a plan, but if you think it is really that much better, you can recruit 4 other people who feel the same (and have never voted on either post).  You can then get everyone to vote to reopen it and then vote to close the other as a duplicate.

But failing that, I would just answer the duplicate question if you have a good answer to it that isn't already there.

Comment: This is a clear and complete answer. It made me think that instead of asking for re-opening the closed question, I should ask to clarified/simplify the open one, which happens to be a community question.